# UIButton width doesn't increase based on text if insets are given

Tags: uibutton, autolayout, swift4, width

I have given **trailing**, **top** and **height** constraints to the button.
As you can see in the attached screenshot, if I remove all the insets given, then button looks perfect and button fits based on text length.

But I want to give right-left title insets as well as left image inset.

Then button is not displaying text properly as shown in the attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Auto-layout can be a little tricky when adjusting the Title Label of a `UIButton`.

From Apple's docs for [titleEdgeInsets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624010-titleedgeinsets):

> This property is used only for positioning the title during layout. The button does not use this property to determine intrinsicContentSize and sizeThatFits(_:).

You have a couple options...

One is to subclass `UIButton` and override `.intrinsicContentSize`.

Another option, which may be better for your case, is to adjust the `Content Insets` instead of the `Title Insets`.

As you described, this button has Top / Trailing / Height constraints:

[image]

[image]

Note that the Left value for the Image Inset is a *negative* value. You may / probably will want to tweak the values I used.

[image]